# Directive use a class selector

Tags: angular

I have the following directive which selects elements with class `.class`

```
import {Component, Directive} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '.box',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick($event.target)'
  }
})
export class Box {
  onClick(btn) {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

And the template below:

```
<div class="box">tst</div>
```

What am I missing to make it work upon clicking on the div?

Comment: This should work. You probably forgot to import `Box` directive in module's declaration array

Comment: Yeah, that's it, I forgot the declaration imports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Box directive should be imported in the module declarations

```
declarations: [ 
 ...
 Box 
]
```